# Integrating SSL with MySql

Tags: mysql, ssl, access-denied

I'm trying to setting up `ssl` for `mysql` by referring [this](http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=448). 
I'm able to complete first 3 steps but having issue with the 4th which is as following:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ssluser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'ssluser' REQUIRE SSL;
```

After executing this statement when I try to run `mysql -ussluser -pssluser -P3430 --ssl-key=`, it shows following error: **Can't connect to MySql server on 'localhost' (10061)**

I tried to connect to mysql using `mysql -ussluser -pssluser`, but it shows: **Access denied for user 'ssluser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**

How can it say *Access Denied* when I have already executed *GRANT* statement.

**Note that** I executed `mysql -ussluser -pssluser` **before** using *GRANT* atetement and I was able to connect to `mysql`. I execute `mysql> CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_SSL=1;` at this point of time (which should enable SSL???).

Also, If I try `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'ssluser'@'localhost';`
I get

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'ssluser\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*C56A6573BEE146CB8243543295FD80ADCE588EFF\' REQUIRE SSL WITH GRANT OPTION
```

I'm trying it from couple of days but have found nothing. Any help appreciated.

### Edit1

When I use `show global variables like 'have_%ssl';` I get

```
have_openssl    DISABLED
have_ssl        DISABLED
```

and when I use this `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';` I get

```
Ssl_cipher  _________
```

Also, I have created all server and client certificated and placed them in `certs` directory inside `mysql server` root directory.

Comment: Did you do a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`?

Comment: Re the 10061 message - are you connecting to mySQL on the right port? How are you connecting to mySQL?

Comment: How about step 5: updating your config file and restarting the server? MySQL will not know to use ssl connections until then

Comment: @Pekka웃 : 3306 is the default port for me. Also I'm able to connect with *root* but without using `REQUIRE SSL` in `GRANT`.

Comment: @Mchl : ALready tried : But no help :(

Comment: I posted a response that might help you in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402828/integrating-ssl-with-mysql-access-denied .  Is this a duplicate of that one, or is this slightly different?

Answer (score 0):

You've not provided any information about the OS for the server or client, nor where you sourced the executables, nor how the DBMS is configured.

> mysql -ussluser -pssluser -P3430 --ssl-key=

IIRC, the ssl-key option is used when you've set up the user account to provide a client certificate for authentication (GRANT....REQUIRE X509;). And in this scenario you need to give it a client cert file as an argument.

But you've only said that it should use SSL - i.e. the client is anonymous for SSL purposes. However the client still needs to validate the server - hence mysql should be started with [--ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/ssl-options.html#option_general_ssl-ca) or --ssl-capath=directory_name.

You also need to ensure that the server is configured for SSL support - the ini file or startup script should contain a reference to the certificate it's going to use and the port on which it handles SSL connections. Also SSL support must be compiled into the binary and any relevant shared object files be available. If config says SSL but the DBMS can't do SSL, then you should get some indication of this from the server logs.

Comment: when you say `--ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem`, it implies to something like this `mysql -ussluser -pssluser -P3430 --ssl-ca="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\certs\ca-cert.pem"`, Correct?

Comment: It's giving following error: `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)`

Comment: Also, can you please guide me through last para of your answer?

Comment: Comment 1: yes. Comment 2: did you check that the ca-cert bundle contains the ca you used for your certificate? Comment 3: only if I can bill you by the hour

Comment: I dint get your reply related to comment 2?

Comment: My `ca-cert.pem` is placed at above mentioned location only.