# Integrating ssl with mysql - Access Denied

Tags: mysql, ssl, access-denied

I'm trying to setting up `ssl` for `mysql` by referring [this](http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=448). 
I'm able to complete first 3 steps but having issue with the 4th which is as following:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ssluser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'ssluser' REQUIRE SSL;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then I restart the mysql server.

After executing this statement when I try to run `mysql -ussluser -pssluser -P3306 --ssl-key="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\certs\ca-cert.pem"`, 
it shows following error: **Access denied for user 'ssluser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**
I'm using *3306* here as it's my default port.

How it can say *Access Denied* when I have already executed *GRANT* statement.

**Note that**

- I executed `mysql -ussluser -pssluser` **before** using *GRANT* statement with `REQUIRE SSL` and I was able to connect to `mysql`.
- If I try `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'ssluser'@'localhost';`
  I get

  ```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \'ssluser\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*C56A6573BEE146CB8243543295FD80ADCE588EFF\' REQUIRE SSL WITH GRANT OPTION
  ```
- Before executing *GRANT* statement, I was able to connect to *workbench* through *ssluser*. But now its giving **access denied** error.
- When I use `show global variables like 'have_%ssl';` I get

  have_openssl    DISABLED
  have_ssl        DISABLED
- and when I use this `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';` I get

  Ssl_cipher  _________
- I have created all server and client **certificates** and placed them in `certs` directory inside `mysql server` root directory.

I'm trying it from couple of days but have found nothing. Any help appreciated.

I'm doing this for the first time. Can anyone guide me through detailed procedure to do this?

Answer (score 8):

I was struggling with a similar error message today and here is what I discovered.

1. The "REQUIRE SSL" option for the GRANT only requires SSL for connection and does not require a client side certificate to be provided.
2. The mysql CLI does not handle SSL like I expected.  For example, on MySQL 5.5, the `--ssl` option doesn't seem to really enable the SSL transport.
3. I had to add the option `--ssl-cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA` to get the mysql client to really use SSL and allow authentication with the client.

Here are the exact steps I used to setup my new user:

```
CREATE USER 'ssl-user'@'%' identified by '<password>';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'ssl-user'@'%' identified by '<password>' REQUIRE SSL;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `your-database`.* TO 'ssl-user'@'%';
```

Comment: For me I had to add --ssl-cipher=DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA and shorten the password to 50 characters to let me connect remotely.

Comment: +1: Was finally able to get MySQL Workbench to connect over SSL by specifying setting SSL Cipher to `DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA`!